# Full firstnames in agsm bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, harvard-style

I am using `natbib` and the `agsm` bibliography style, as I have made a set-up for the in text citations, that fit the formalia requirements where I study.

I do have one problem though: I would like to show authors' full first names in the bibliography instead of abbreviated first names. I would like to acquire this without changing how the citations look in the text.

Right now I get:

> Stiglitz, J. E. and Rosengard, J. K.

Instead, I would like

> Stiglitz, Joseph E. and Rosengard, Jay K.

Is there a way to acquire this?

I have created an example of my setup below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}\usepackage[margin = 1in, headheight=14pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[semicolon]{natbib}

%Set up as formalia dictates
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{\&}}

%Test bibliography
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Book{Stiglitz2015,
  author    = {Joseph E. Stiglitz and Jay K. Rosengard},
  editor    = {Jack Repcheck},
  publisher = {Norton},
  title     = {Economics of the {P}ublic {S}ector},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {Forth edition (International Student Edition)},}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is a citation \citep{Stiglitz2015}.

\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution, make a copy of the file, and call the copy (say) `agsm-ffn.bst`. ("ffn" is short for "full first names".)
- Open the file `agsm-ffn.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the bst file, change both instances of the string `"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}"` (located in the functions `format.authors` and `format.editors`) to `"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}"`. Next, change the lone instance of `"{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` (in the function `format.editors.reverse`) to `"{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"`.
- Save the file `agsm-ffn.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` to `\bibliographystyle{agsm-ffn}` and perform a full LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX recompilation cycle.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Works like a charm - thank you very much! I've been trying to fix this for longer than I want to admit. I had been looking at other questings messing with the bst-file. If you do not mind - how do I find that ff is the short for fullname?

Comment: @Lea - You're most welcome. In the bst programming patois, `ff` indeed stands for "full first name(s)", `f.` stands for "abbreviated first name(s) followed by a period", and `f` (not used by the `agsm` style) stands for "abbreviated first name not followed by a period". For an intro to BibTeX programming, I heartily recommend Nicolas Markey's [Tame the BeaST](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast),